# NavigationController back button not appearing until after view loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I have two view controllers, the first embedded in a navigation controller.  One of the buttons on the first view pushes the second onto the navigation stack.  Great.  Except that the back button only appears when that second view is completely finished animating into the window.  This would be fine except that the title of that view shows right away:

[image]

[image]

This creates a weird discrepancy where one element appears right away and the other just kind of pops in afterwards.  Any way to have the back button appear right away?  I'm using a custom button btw:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: A little more information is needed here. How are you performing the transition (segue hooked up in storyboard / `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:)` / `pushViewController(_:animated:)`)? Where (in code) are you setting the `backBarButtonItem`? In my brief test, I can only get the behaviour you describe when setting the `leftBarButtonItem` in `viewDidAppear(_:)`.

Comment: Also, the UI you describe is somewhat non-idiomatic in iOS. Following a push transition, users will generally expect to see a back arrow with text that describes the previous screen. Your setup (with a `Cancel` button on the left) looks more like it a modal presentation. Of course, I don't know the full flow of your app's UI, but just thought it worth mentioning in case it helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the process of figuring out how to make it more like a modal that slides up from the bottom, then on cancel slides back down.  However, for the sake of understanding what's going on with a normal push transition I'm trying to figure out the back button not displaying right away in this scenario.  As for how I'm performing the transition, simple button segue to the second view via the storyboard.  I'm creating the custom back button in the first view controller, but the issue persists even when i use the default button, though it starts fading in slightly earlier for whatever reason

Comment: Where in the first view controller are you creating the back button, in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`? I'm struggling to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Eh it's alright.  I'll just change it to modal.  Can you just tell me, presenting something modally I shouldn't be using a NavigationController, right?  So I would create a custom top bar with a cancel button and all that? If so, should that be a Navigation Bar or just a View?  Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer which covers a few points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more details, I'm not sure of the reason behind the behaviour you're describing. However, I'll try and give an idea of how to setup these kinds of transition. Since you're working in a storyboard, it's pretty straightforward.

In your storyboard, you'll start off with a view controller embedded in a navigation controller, and a second view controller that you want to transition to. Control-drag from your first VC's button to the second VC scene, and choose a "Show" action segue which will cause a navigation push transition - I think this is the way you have your storyboard configured.

You can change your back button title directly in the storyboard. Choose the first VC scene and select its navigation item object from the document outline on the left. In the attributes inspector on the right, just change the "Back Button" field to whatever you want the button to say when you push to the second VC. This will keep the back arrow icon users expect.

If you want to use a push transition but show a normal-looking button without the arrow, you can hide the back button in your second VC's `viewDidLoad()`:

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Then, back in your storyboard, drag out a bar button item to the left side of the navigation bar of your second VC, and give it a custom title etc.

However, what you really want for this setup is a modal transition, and doing this is as simple as changing your segue type to "Present Modally" in the storyboard. This will present the second VC *above* the navigation stack, so a navigation bar will not be shown by default. Rather than dragging a standalone navigation bar out from the objects panel (which will give you some headaches trying to get it to extend under the status bar), embed your second VC in its own navigation controller which will implicitly add a navigation bar. Then, you can drag out a bar button item to the left side of the bar and hook it up via an unwind segue, or use an `IBAction` method and call `presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)`.

Comment: THIS is an explanation. I fixed my storyboard and now it works